# Java tomcat application hangs, can't restart tomcat after stopping

Tags: java, tomcat7

I have deployed a mature web application to a new server on tomcat 7.  The database the system uses is quite empty as we're in the early stages of configuring it for use.

Going to the app, you get a login page.  Log in and it usually takes you to the main page of the app.

But after coming in the following morning, we always get the same problem:

1. We bring up the login screen - no problem
2. Enter our username and password - system hangs
3. We go to tomcat and using 
   the system tray,  stop the service.
4. The stopping service progress bar appears then goes away, but the status
   on the tomcat properties dialog still shows 'Started' and both the Start 
   and Stop buttons are disabled.
5. We check the tomcat logs and there are no errors
6. We restart the server and it works ok again

There is nothing obvious we can see.  A tomcat 'Find Leaks' request shows nothing, and looking at the heap sizes on VisualVM shows a consistent pattern of heap takeup followed by garbage collection bringing it back down to the same low level (so no apparent leaks)

I thought it may be mysql connections timing out, but that shouldnt be the case because if I log in with the wrong password, the system goes to the database to check the password and returns as expected with 'wrong password'.  The only point at which it fails is if you enter the correct password.

The only clue we have is that there is an error when logging in, where the system uses some custom code to figure out the users' host name:

```
2019-02-14 08:10:14,277 08:10:14.277 [http-bio-8080-exec-9] ERROR com.sw.app.ui.UserAuthenticatedWebSession - Unknown host!
java.net.UnknownHostException: null
            at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.getHostByAddr(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
            at java.net.InetAddress$2.getHostByAddr(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
            at com.sw.app.data.utils.NetUtilities.getHostName(NetUtilities.java:114) ~[app-data-4.0.15.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
```

This is only invoked if the user logs in successfully to store where they are logging in from, but the exception is caught in the code and then just logged rather than propagated upwards, and then we use a default 'unknown' host name.  This is the code:

```
  public static String getHostName( InetAddress inaHost ) throws UnknownHostException
  {
    try {
      Class<? extends InetAddress> clazz = Class.forName( "java.net.InetAddress" ).asSubclass( InetAddress.class );
      Constructor<?>[] constructors = clazz.getDeclaredConstructors();
      constructors[0].setAccessible( true );
      InetAddress ina = (InetAddress)constructors[0].newInstance();
      Field[] fields = ina.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
      for( Field field : fields ) {
        // Depends on the version of java we are dealing with:
        // Older version - single nameservice
        if( field.getName().equals( "nameService" ) ) {
          return getHostName( field.get( null ), inaHost );
        } else if( field.getName().equals( "nameServices" ) ) {
          // newer version - multiple name services possible
          StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
          field.setAccessible( true );
          // A list of nameservice objects
          @SuppressWarnings( "unchecked" )
          List<Object> nameServices = (List<Object>)field.get( null );
          for( Object nameService : nameServices ) {
            String hostName = getHostName( nameService, inaHost );
            if( builder.length() > 0 ) {
              builder.append( ", " );
            }
            builder.append( hostName );
          }
          return builder.toString();
        }
      }
    } catch( ClassNotFoundException cnfe ) {
      throw new InvalidOperationException( "Class not found when looking up host name", cnfe );
    } catch( IllegalAccessException iae ) {
      throw new InvalidOperationException( "Cannot access method/field", iae );
    } catch( InstantiationException ie ) {
      throw new InvalidOperationException( "Cannot instantiate class", ie );
    } catch( InvocationTargetException ite ) {
      throw (UnknownHostException)ite.getCause();
    }
    return null;
  }

  /**
   * Get the host name using reflection on the hidden class implementation of the InetAddress details.
   * @param p_nameService
   * @param p_address
   * @return
   * @throws IllegalAccessException
   * @throws InvocationTargetException
   */
  private static String getHostName( Object nameService, InetAddress address ) throws IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {
    Method[] methods = nameService.getClass().getDeclaredMethods();
    for( Method method : methods ) {
      // The nameService is assumed to have a method, getHostByAddr, which takes the byte[] inet address
      if( method.getName().equals( "getHostByAddr" ) ) {
        method.setAccessible( true );
        return (String)method.invoke( nameService, address.getAddress() );
      }
    }
    return "";
  }
```

Does anyone have similar issues?

-- Edit --

Here is the database configuration bean class.

```
@Configuration
public class AppPersistence {

  private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger( AppPersistence.class );

  protected static final String INTERNAL_IP_DOMAIN = "*******";
  protected static final String JDBC_PROTOCOL = "jdbc:mysql://";
  protected static final String DEFAULT_DATABASE_NAME = "*******";

  /** The path for context-based property lookups */
  protected static final String CONTEXT_LOOKUP_PATH = "java:comp/env";

  /** This is the default location for the database - on the same machine as the deployment */
  protected static final String DB_LOCAL    = JDBC_PROTOCOL + "localhost:3306/" + DEFAULT_DATABASE_NAME;

  @Bean
  public DataSource createDataSource() throws Exception {
    BasicDataSource source = new BasicDataSource();

    // allow for parameterised config
    source.setDriverClassName( Driver.class.getName() );
    source.setUrl( getProperty( "app.database.url", DB_LOCAL ) );
    source.setUsername( getProperty( "app.database.username", "*****" ) );
    source.setPassword( getProperty( "app.database.password", "****" ) );

    LOGGER.warn( "Connecting to: " + source.getUrl() );

    return source;
  }

  protected String getProperty( String name, String default ) {
    // first check system properties
    String val = System.getProperty( name );
    if( val != null ) {
      logLookup( "System Properties", name, val );
      return val;
    }
    // check environment variables
    val = System.getenv( name );
    if( val != null ) {
      logLookup( "System Environment Variables", name, val );
      return val;
    }
    // if we are deployed to a container, check the environment variables in that.
    try {
      Context context = InitialContext.doLookup( "java:comp/env" );
      if( context != null ) {
        Object valObj = context.lookup( name );
        if( valObj != null ) {
          logLookup( "Context", name, valObj.toString() );
          return valObj.toString();
        }
      }
    } catch( NamingException e ) {
      // if running on a dev machine this will probably happen
      LOGGER.warn( "Could not find context for lookup of " + p_name + " - assuming running in dev mode with defaults.  Error was: " + e.toString( true ) );
      LOGGER.info( "Error received on lookup of " + name + ":", e );
    }
    return p_default;
  }

  protected void logLookup( String source, String lookup, String value ) {
    if( value.contains( "password" ) ) {
      // avoid displaying any password info
      LOGGER.warn( "Successfully looked up sensitive value from " + source + " for name '" + lookup + "': [******]" );
    } else {
      LOGGER.warn( "Successfully looked up value from " + source + " for name '" + lookup + "': '" + value + "'" );
    }
  }

  @Bean
  public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory( DataSource dataSource ) {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    entityManagerFactory.setPersistenceUnitName( "com.sw.app.data.persistence" );
    entityManagerFactory.setDataSource( dataSource );
    entityManagerFactory.setJpaVendorAdapter( new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter() );
    entityManagerFactory.setLoadTimeWeaver( new InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver() );
    entityManagerFactory.setJpaDialect( new HibernateJpaDialect() );
    entityManagerFactory.setPackagesToScan( "com.sw.app.data", "com.sw.app.rawimport",
                                            "com.sw.app.view", "com.sw.app.warranty" );

    entityManagerFactory.setJpaPropertyMap( hibernateJpaProperties( dataSource ) );
    return entityManagerFactory;
  }

  private Map<String, ?> hibernateJpaProperties( DataSource dataSource ) {
    HashMap<String, String> properties = new HashMap<>();

    // Need to copy these values over, otherwise c3p0 can't see them.
    if( dataSource instanceof BasicDataSource ) {
      BasicDataSource source = (BasicDataSource)p_dataSource;

      properties.put( "hibernate.connection.driver_class", source.getDriverClassName() );
      properties.put( "hibernate.connection.url", source.getUrl() );
      properties.put( "hibernate.connection.username", source.getUsername() );
      properties.put( "hibernate.connection.password", source.getPassword() );
    }

    // Added to avoid some merge problems when updating entities (eg contact to custimport)
    properties.put( "hibernate.event.merge.entity_copy_observer", "allow" );

    // Second level cache
    properties.put( "hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache", "true" );
    properties.put( "hibernate.cache.use_query_cache", "true" );
    properties.put( "hibernate.cache.provider_class", "org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider" );
    properties.put( "hibernate.cache.region.factory_class", EhCacheRegionFactory.class.getName() );
    properties.put( "hibernate.generate_statistics", "false" );

    properties.put( "hibernate.show_sql", "false" );
    properties.put( "hibernate.format_sql", "false" );

    // validate | update | create | create-drop -->
    properties.put( "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update" );
    properties.put( "hibernate.dialect", MySQL5Dialect.class.getName() );

    // [main] WARN  org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder - HHH000457: Joined inheritance hierarchy [com.sw.system4.data.collateral.AbstractCollateral] defined explicit @DiscriminatorColumn.  Legacy Hibernate behavior was to ignore the @DiscriminatorColumn.  However, as part of issue HHH-6911 we now apply the explicit @DiscriminatorColumn.  If you would prefer the legacy behavior, enable the `hibernate.discriminator.ignore_explicit_for_joined` setting (hibernate.discriminator.ignore_explicit_for_joined=true) -->
    properties.put( "hibernate.discriminator.ignore_explicit_for_joined", "true" );

    //properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files", "insert-data.sql");
    //properties.put("hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy", "org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy");

    // This wasnt required in persistence.xml, but for some reason is here.
    properties.put( "hibernate.connection.provider_class", C3P0ConnectionProvider.class.getName() );

    // just adding c3p0 props was enough in persistence.xml, but not here.
    properties.put( "hibernate.c3p0.min_size", "5" );
    properties.put( "hibernate.c3p0.max_size", "20" );
    properties.put( "hibernate.c3p0.timeout", "300" ); // 5mins
    properties.put( "hibernate.c3p0.max_statements", "50" );
    properties.put( "hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period", "100" );
    properties.put( "hibernate.c3p0.preferredTestQuery", "select 1" );
    properties.put( "hibernate.c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckout", "true" );
    properties.put( "hibernate.c3p0.numHelperThreads", "12" );
    properties.put( "hibernate.c3p0.maxStatementsPerConnection", "25" );
    properties.put( "hibernate.c3p0.statementCacheNumDeferredCloseThreads", "1" );

    return l_properties;
  }

  @Bean
  public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager( EntityManagerFactory emf ) {
    JpaTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    jpaTransactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory( emf );
    return jpaTransactionManager;
  }
}
```

Comment: If it database related, show its configuration

Answer (score 0):

What is your database? Is it a *Cloud Database*? I had a similar problem with *CloudSQL*. What happened was when some active connections didn't do anything with the database, from the database side, it rejects the connection after some hours. But on the application side, you will see it as an active connection. I have used *Apache DBCP* pool, and I was able to solve the problem using this in the database configurations.

```
    dataSource.setValidationQuery("SELECT 1");
    dataSource.setTestOnBorrow(true);
    dataSource.setTestWhileIdle(true);
```

Because you are using *C3P0*, following commands should work for you.

```
    hibernate.dbcp.testOnBorrow=true
    hibernate.dbcp.testOnReturn=true
    hibernate.dbcp.validationQuery=SELECT 1
```

Comment: Hi sueesh, Thanks for the suggestion, I added this config to the properties and unfortunately it hasn't made a difference.  I also commented out the code to get the host name and that also didnt make a difference, suggesting it was a symptom not the cause.

Comment: Hi fancyplants , My suggestion is to change the database pool(C3P0) and check problem is fixed?

Comment: hi sugeesh we currently use c3p0 can you recommend an alternative?

Comment: Try, HikariCP. It is really efficient.